# lynxjura dataset for R

Tags: r

I am after this dataset:

http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=adehabitat:lynxjura

Is anyone aware of where to find/download it?

Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you've linked to indicates that the dataset is provided by the [`adehabitat`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitat/index.html) package:

> lynxjura {**adehabitat**}

You need to install the package, load it, and then you'll be able to use the dataset:

```
> install.packages('adehabitat')
> library('adehabitat')
> data(lynxjura)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the adehabitat package:

```
 library(adehabitat)
 data(lynxjura)
```

You may need to install it first, and please note that this package recently updated into four new separate packages, so investigate them and find which has these data now.

(It's adehabitatMA - the legacy package adehabitat encourages use of the new 4 packages, but the transition is not yet complete it seems).